# Using SUM to calculate A LOT of data groups in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by, sum

Now, this is a tricky one as I am trying to group each student together and find the SUM of Unit Credit for EACH student at ONLY level THREE and ONLY at DIST.   There are over 5000 students so previous examples are difficult to work in!

Here is an example of the raw data.

Table 1 (tblawardedlearners)

```
 Student No      Unit      Unit Credit     Grade
```

```
  1432          English         1          DIST
  1432          French          2          DIST
  1432          Maths           2          DIST
  1432          History         3          MERIT
  1432          Geography       1          DIST
  1432          Spanish         2          DIST
  1432          Science1        2          MERIT
  1432          Science2        2          PASS
  1431          English         1          DIST
  1431          Maths           3          MERIT
  1431          Science1        1          DIST
  1431          Biology         3          DIST
  1431          Sport           1          MERIT
  1431          French          2          PASS
  1436          Cooking         2          DIST
  1436          Woodwork        1          DIST
  1436          SQL             2          PASS
  1436          CompSci         1          DIST
  1436          Psych           1          MERIT
  1436          Maths           3          PASS
```

Table 2 (viewunitsonrun)

```
 Unit Level

   ONE
   THREE
   TWO
   TWO
   THREE
   THREE
   ONE
   ONE
   THREE
   TWO
   TWO
   THREE
   THREE
   ONE
   ONE
   THREE
   TWO
   TWO
   THREE
   THREE
   ONE
```

Ideally I would just need three columns

```
 Student No      Level      TOTAL Unit Credit   Grade
```

```
  1432           THREE            2               DIST
  1436           THREE            2               DIST
```

Here is my code so far

```
SELECT SUM (intunitcredit) as TOTALunitcredit, intlearnerID
FROM tblawardedlearners
LEFT JOIN viewunitsonrun
ON tblawardedlearners.strunitcode = viewunitsonrun.strUnitCode
FROM strUnitLevelName = 'THREE'
AND strUnitGrade = 'DIST'
GROUP BY intLearnerID
```

NB - strunitlevelname is the only column that is required from viewunitsonrun (table), all the others are in tblawardedlearners.

The results I get way out there (5000 for each student??). I have also tried to add those extra columns but flags an error always.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your sample data suggests one table and yet your query mentions two.  Please fix the question so it makes sense.

Comment: When testing, Remove the SUM/GROUP BY and see if you get duplicate rows from tblawardedlearners. My guess is `tblawardedlearners.strunitcode = viewunitsonrun.strUnitCode` can match several records in the viewunitsonrun table.

Comment: Hi there, No it aint I have tried it.   There are exact matches all the way through with no duplicates.